# Windows 11 Insider Build 22567.100 - ICO files giving "Runtime error 7:Out of memory" with ImageList.Add in VB6 code

Tags: vb6, windows-11

When we are loading ICO (icon files) using 'ImageList.ListImages.Add' method in VB6 code, it is throwing "runtime error 7 - out of memory" message , in a **Windows 11 PC with Insider Build 22567.100**. It is working properly when ICO files are loaded using LoadPicture method. The code is working fine with older Windows 11 builds and issue is occurring only in this build.

For BMP files it is working fine with 'ImageList.ListImages.Add' method, and error is occurring only for ICO files. We are using ICO files with bit depth as 32.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Apparently there is a bug in that insider version of W11 which is causing lots of crashes. This is mentioned in the release [docs](https://blog.getpaint.net/2022/03/08/paint-net-4-3-9-is-now-available/) for the latest version of Paint.net under "Changes since v4.3.8:" which was released today.